# XML to CSV using python pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas

Hi I am trying to convert my xml data to pandas data frame but unable to parse all data.
its a 13mb xml file.

I want to extract text inside "NodeName", i tried various other ways of Element Tree but failed.
Below is my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Ib440ConfigGetResponse xmlns="http://Airspan.Netspan.WebServices">
            <Ib440ConfigGetResult>
                <ErrorCode>OK</ErrorCode>
                <NodeResult>
                    <NodeResultCode>OK</NodeResultCode>
                    <NodeName>INAPKVLIVGLRTW6001ENBIB5004</NodeName>
                    <Ib440Config>
                        <Name>INAPKVLIVGLRTW6001ENBIB5004</Name>
                        <Hardware>iBridge 440-221</Hardware>
                        <Description>I-AP-KVLI-ENB-6001</Description>
                        <ManagedMode>Managed</ManagedMode>
                        <Site>Kavali</Site>
                        <Region>Andhra Pradesh</Region>
                        <NbifEventAlarmForwarding>Enabled</NbifEventAlarmForwarding>
                        <ConfigMode>OptimizedModeC</ConfigMode>
                        <MediumAccessMethod>CSMA</MediumAccessMethod>
                        <WirelessProtocol>802.11n</WirelessProtocol>
                        <HtSupportedMcs>MCS0-15</HtSupportedMcs>
                        <VhtSupportedMcs>MCS0-7</VhtSupportedMcs>
                        <CellRadiusRange>Short</CellRadiusRange>
                        <GuardInterval>Long</GuardInterval>
                        <Frequency>5850</Frequency>
```

Below is a small code i try bt it shows only 4 line.

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
import pandas as pd
df = pdx.read_xml('1111s.xml')
df
```

result i get it from
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give `BeautifulSoup` a try.

You could read xml file as a bs4 object and then use bs4 methods to get the attributes you need (and convert the result into a dataframe).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("1111s.xml", "r") as f:
    xml_data = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, "xml")
soup.find("NodeName").get_text(strip=True)
# 'INAPKVLIVGLRTW6001ENBIB5004'


# in a loop
data = []
for element in soup.find("NodeName").find_next_siblings():
    data.append({
        "Name": element.find("Name").get_text(strip=True),
        "Hardware": element.find("Hardware").get_text(strip=True),
        "Site": element.find("Site").get_text(strip=True)
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
    Name                        Hardware        Site
0   INAPKVLIVGLRTW6001ENBIB5004 iBridge 440-221 Kavali
```

Comment: just an example to get you started

Comment: Thanks Mate for your kind support :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the XML, you would need to make a list of tags you want to navigate to get to the "root" tag. If I have to guess, then:

```py
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

root_tag_list = ['soap:Envelope', 'soap:Body', 'Ib440ConfigGetResponse', 'Ib440ConfigGetResult', 'NodeResult', 'Ib440Config']

df = pdx.read_xml('1111s.xml', root_tag_list)

df
```

could work.

Comment: i get this error, 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str